# Apache htaccess help to RewriteRule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Here's what I want to do:

```
mysite.com/video      >    mysite.com/index.php?find=video
mysite.com/video/pag/10      >    mysite.com/index.php?find=video&pag=10
mysite.com/video/min/20/pag/10      >    mysite.com/index.php?find=video&pag=10&min=20
mysite.com/video/min/20/pag/10/max/30      >    mysite.com/index.php?find=video&pag=10&min=20&max=30
```

etc.

The parameters min,pag,max can be in random order. For example these urls 
    mysite.com/video/min/20/pag/10/max/30
    mysite.com/video/max/30/pag/10/min/20
have to return always mysite.com/index.php?find=video&pag=10&min=20&max=30

I spend all the days without any solutions
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was about to do the tedious task of trying to write the whole thing. But then I thought why the hell not do:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

And then in `index.php` just parse `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and extract what you need.

Work smart, not hard.